Can you explain the Georgi–Jarlskog mass relation?
I am trying to understand the Georgi Mass relation in $SU(5)$
As far as I was aware the symmetry breaking occurs only with the various charge quantum numbers (colour, weak charge, electromagnetic). So how would it affect anything to do with the family number? i.e. Why would it predict different mass relations between say down quark and electron in family 1 and bottom quark and tau in family 3? Shouldn't all families be treated the same? Can anyone explain this in simple terms? The result is often quoted but I can't seem to find the reason.
These don't seem to be predictions, more like fitting the model to match the data.

" Shouldn't all families be treated the same?" If the relevant masses are different, the RG treats them differently, and GJ tells you BEGN is the conceptual paradigm on this they tweak.

I see. I was confused as it says it is a prediction of the SU(5) model. But actually they tweaked the model to give those particular mass ratios.
